# How to set Quodlibet as default music player?

Tags: music, default-programs, quodlibet

I am interested in having Quodlibet show up in the "Default Applications" menu in System Settings > Details, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make any music player that comes with sound indicator integration the default player in there we may from 13.04 install and run [unity-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool) [image: Install unity-tweak-tool]. Open the *"Panel"* settings and choose any of installed players:

[image]

The example above will then make Guayadeque the default player in the sound indicator:

[image]

Of course if we prefer not to install an additional application, or if a player such as Quod Libet does not come with full indicator sound integration we can also do this with **dconf-editor** (from [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools] in Ubuntu < 13.04):

[image]

Quod Libet need the MPRIS plugin ([quodlibet-plugins](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quodlibet-plugins) [image: Install quodlibet-plugins]) for full player control.

Comment: Though I'd rather know the inner workings of the system, your post is very complete and will possibly be most helpful for anybody who reads this Q-A, thanks for your effort!

Comment: @WolterHellmund you already did the MIME approach nicely. I felt people who come here by Google might also want to hear about Inidicator integration.

Comment: This doesn't work for quod libet, which was the OPs original question.

Comment: @Takkat - I tried the dconf trick just now and now Quod Libet appears in the menu...which is great.  However, when I click on it, nothing happens...just doesn't run it.

Comment: @Takkat - I asked over at the Quod forum and they said their mpris plugin only works with QL 3.0 which is not in Ubuntu stable yet.  Perhaps it is just a matter of time...

Comment: Installing and enabling the mpris plugin for Quod on 13.04 now works and has now allowed me perfect control from the sound indicator menu.  Start/stop/pause -- everything Just Works.

Comment: @HDave: thank you for the feedback (see edit) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, read about and found it: just make sure you reference `quodlibet.desktop` in your `mimeapps.list` file (local copy at `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`).

You can set it default right away just by having the following line in the mentioned file: `audio/x-vorbis+ogg=quodlibet.desktop`.