# Can I add Quod Libet controls to the sound menu?

Tags: indicator-sound, quodlibet

I recently [installed the latest version of Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/downloads.html#ubuntu). However, unlike other music players (for example, Rhythmbox) it doesn't have play/pause/prev/next controls under the sound menu.

How can I add them?

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/294204/how-to-set-quodlibet-as-default-music-player

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Start Quod Libet
- From the menu, select Music > Plugins
- Locate "MPRIS D-Bus support" in the plugin list.
- Tick to enable.
- Close the plugin list.

(Optional) In the plugin details, tick "Hide main window on close". This will trigger more Rhythmbox-like behaviour: when you close the Quod Libet window, the application icon will no longer appear in the launcher, but QL will still be running and accessible from the sound menu.

Answer via https://github.com/quod-libet/quodlibet/issues/1493