# Make Gmusicbrowser default music player

Tags: 14.04, system-settings, default-programs, music-player, gmusicbrowser

This program doesn't appear in the "Default applications" > "Music" menu at "System settings" > "Details".
I know that is posible to manually set every audio format to open with it. But is there a way to make it appear on the menu at System Settings panel?

That way my media keys will work automatically too.

I also know that the media key problem can be sorted out by setting up custom shortcuts but I preffer avoiding that if posible.

My system: Ubuntu 14.04 Unity

**UPDATE:**

I found what it seems to be the correct file to modify:

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

The lines under [Default Applications] looked quite suspicious to me...

But... I were lazy and just replaced every "rhythmbox.desktop" for "gmusicbrowser.desktop". Of course that did the trick helping me setting Gmusicbrowser as default music player in the System Settings panel also I can now launch the player by using the corresponding media key. However I couldn't make the other media keys to work (prev/next/play/pause)...

The problem might lie at the time of installation, I think that Gmusicbrowser isn't registering the mime types that can play, therefore Ubuntu can't realize that it is an audio player, so for now it has to be registered manually.

Comment: It's preety much the same procedures outlined here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/294204/how-to-set-quodlibet-as-default-music-player - for player control you need to activate the MPRIS plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the info Takkat, however that only puts Gmusicbrowser at the top of the Sound Indicator's player list.